# Class not found occurs in migration in laravel, after changing createTable php

Tags: php, laravel

> 1 I made a migration by using

```
$ php artisan make:migration FILE_NAME --create=TABLE_NAME
```

> 2 I modified the class name

> 3 I did

```
php artisan migrate
```

This error happens.

```
   Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : Class 'CreateSettingsTestTable' not found

  at /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:453
    449|     public function resolve($file)
    450|     {
    451|         $class = Str::studly(implode('_', array_slice(explode('_', $file), 4)));
    452| 
  > 453|         return new $class;
    454|     }
    455| 
    456|     /**
    457|      * Get all of the migration files in a given path.

  Exception trace:

  1   Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator::resolve("2021_10_26_165115_create_tests_table")
      /Users/test/test/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:189

  2   Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator::runUp("/Users/test/test/test/test/database/migrations/2021_10_26_165855_create_tests_table.php")
    /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:165

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

> 4 So I tried this

```
$ composer dump-autoload
Generating optimized autoload files
Class App\CsvManager located in ./app/Manager/CsvManager.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class App\Notifications\VerifyEmailJP located in ./app/Notifications/PasswordResetNotification.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi
Discovered Package: arrilot/laravel-widgets
Discovered Package: facade/ignition
Discovered Package: fideloper/proxy
Discovered Package: intervention/image
Discovered Package: larapack/doctrine-support
Discovered Package: laravel/tinker
Discovered Package: laravel/ui
Discovered Package: nesbot/carbon
Discovered Package: nunomaduro/collision
Discovered Package: tcg/voyager
Package manifest generated successfully.
Generated optimized autoload files containing 5060 classes
```

> 5 But nothing changed.

What should I do next to migrate the modified createTable file?

Answer (score 0):

> autoload_classmap.php

is a PSR-4 standard file that holds the list of all classes that need to be included in the project with its namespaces, `composer dump-autoload` command regenerate the autoload_classmap.php.

to reganerate the class map try to run this command

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but...
my console  says
[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]  
  Command "autoload-dump" is not defined.

Comment: I am sorry the previous command is deprecated, try this one: composer dump-autoload

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Thanks Nico for suggestion, I am pretty new with StackOverflow contribution best practices and rules, sure I will edit my answer and add explanation about the issue